# How are business travel expenses usually reported when using the Dutch public transport system?

Tags: public-transport, netherlands, business-travel

What is the best way to get receipts of the actual trips when filing expense reports during business travel in the Netherlands?

The specificity is the use of the OV-chipkaart with preloaded balance to pay for the trips.

If I top up my card before travel, or I bring an existing one with remaining balance from a previous visit, there is no proof of the actual travel covered by the expense.

The company may want to know which routes were covered to allow reimbursement. How is this case typically handled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [OV-chipkaart](https://www.ov-chipkaart.nl/) website lets you review the travel history for a given card, you can then select which trips to include and which to exclude and generate a PDF document listing those trips and their costs.

The bad part is that if you have an anonymous OV-chipkaart, the Belastingdienst (Dutch tax office) supposedly does not accept this PDF as a tax invoice (perhaps because there's no way to make sure the history belongs to an employee of a given company). At least the generated PDF says so; depending on how strict the accountants at your company are, they might or might not care.

With a personal OV-chip, just generating the PDF and handing that over to the employer has always worked fine for me.